# Como puedo dar efecto de animacion a un div usando DOM en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Juego de Wordle la palabra ingresada aparece en formato de fila y columnas

[image: Juego de Wordle la palabra ingresada aparece en formato de fila y columnas]

Este es el codigo que hace que aparezca la palabra

```js
for (let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
        const SPAN = document.createElement('span');
        SPAN.className = 'letter';
        if (!palabra.includes(intento[i])){
            SPAN.innerHTML = intento[i];
            SPAN.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
        }else if(intento[i]===palabra[i]){
            SPAN.innerHTML = intento[i];
            SPAN.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }else{
            SPAN.innerHTML = intento[i];
            SPAN.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        }
        ROW.appendChild(SPAN)
    }
    GRID.appendChild(ROW)
    console.log(GRID)
```

como puedo hacer para que las letras vayan apareciendo con un poco de retraso entre una y otra?, para darle un efecto animado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar animaciones o transiciones, ambos tienen una "duración", en el caso de las animaciones se llama `animation-duration`. Si a cada letra le das una duración distintas me parece que logras el efecto que buscas.

Como tu tienes un `for` puedes valerte del mismo para ir aumentando progresivamente la duración de la animación a medida que se van creando letras.

Simplifiqué un poco tu código, porque tienes elementos que no agregaste

```js
const palabra="QWERT";

for (let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
    const SPAN = document.createElement('span');
    SPAN.className = 'letter';
    
    //esto es lo importante
    SPAN.style["animation-duration"] = (i+1) + "s";
    
    SPAN.innerHTML = palabra[i];
    ROW.appendChild(SPAN)
}
```

```css
.letter{
  
  display: inline-block;
  animation: animacion;
}
@keyframes animacion {
  0% {
   transform: rotateY(90deg)
  }
  20% {
   transform: rotateY(90deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ROW"></div>
```